# How can I connect Vim to Docker?

Tags: docker, vim

I want to use `jedi-vim` with all dependencies of my dockerized project. As for now I see two ways:

1. Run vim from inside container
2. Copy all dependencies from docker to pipenv.

Is it a clear way to connect vim to docker? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dockerfile:

> FROM ubuntu
>   ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
>   run apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim-python-jedi

Then:

```
> docker build -f dockerfile -t ubuntu-vim .  
> docker run -dit --name u1 ubuntu-vim  
> docker exec u1 vim --version | head -n 1
```

VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Apr 10 2018 21:31:58)